# How to track the Every Change On my project using codeigniter version 3?

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to track the every change done on my project.For that is there any class already existed in codeigniter 3.0.0 version.if not please help me how to track it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use **SVN** or **GIT** to track changes, added new files, removed files etc.

Comment: I don't want to use any version controls.I have to save the every change in my database.